# Is there Javascript alternative for Perl's Text::Template for text template processing and substitution?

Tags: javascript

I would like to dynamically fill (non-HTML) text templates based on properties of objects, and even calling getter functions for those objects to retrieve the data. See code example below. Optionally, executing any arbitrary Javascript (similarly to Perl's Text::Template) would be a bonus.

This for generating text for an RPG game. I don't need to generate any HTML markup. There will not be any (unsafe/untrusted) user input expected.

The text substitution would work as follows:

```
// In file text.js
export const texts = [
  'Name: {level.name}, danger: {level.getDanger()}, val: {value}'
];

// In file fill.js
import {texts} from './text';
const template = new TextTemplate(texts[0]); // What I don't currently have
const myLevel = {
 name: 'test level', getDanger: () => 5
};
const textFilled = template.fill_in({level: myLevel, value: 123});
console.log(textFilled); // prints 'Name: test level, danger: 5, val: 123'
```

JS's own template literal will not work in this case, since the objects/variables used for substitution are not within scope in the `text.js`.
I looked into tagged templates, but could not figure a way to do the substitution.
I'd be interested in any libraries/functions implementing such a text processing.

Comment: Resource requests like this are off-topic on StackOverflow. But there are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of templating tools for JavaScript. Why not try Google?

Comment: seems like you're looking for [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Could you give a short example how template literal would work if the text and substitution happen in different files? See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Most HTML templating libraries (not UI frameworks like React or Angular) don't actually understand HTML. They just operate on strings.

Among the top two pure string templating libraries are [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html) (also available in other languages) and [EJS](https://ejs.co/)

### Handlebars:

```
const template = Handlebars.compile(texts[0]);
console.log(template(variables));
```

Handlebars is deliberately not Turing-complete and strongly discourages logic in templates to prevent business logic creeping into your views. So you cannot pass functions to it to execute. However you can implement helpers which are keywords you can add to the Handlebars parser to execute your own functions.

### EJS:

```
console.log(ejs.render(texts[0], variables));
```

EJS has the exact opposite philosophy to Handlebars. It uses javascript itself as a templating language. You can insert any javascript code into your string to be evaluated. In effect it behaves a bit like PHP. Your string in EJS would look something like:

```
'Name: <%= level.name %>, danger: <%= level.getDanger() %>, val: <%= value %>'
```